# Minimizing-distance property is preserved via diffeomorphism?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemanian manifold. Let $p\in M$ and $(U,\phi)$ is a local chart centered at $p$ such that any two points in $U$ can join by a distance minimizing curve lying in $U$.

I wonder whether the following property is true?:

"For any points $M$ and $N$ in $U$, the image $\phi(\gamma)$ is a straight line in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with also minimizing distance between $\phi(M)$ and $\phi(N)$."

Here $\gamma$ is any distance minimizing curve joining $M$ and $N$ in $U$.

Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. The curve $\phi(\gamma)$ is distance minimizing for the metric $(\phi^{-1})^*g$ on $\phi(U)$ and not for the flat metric coming from $\mathbb R^n$. It would only be true if $\phi$ were an isometry to the flat metric, which would imply that $M$ is flat on $U$.

Comment: Thks. When working on manifolds, we often use the geodesics distance (at least locally), for example, to define a Lispchitz function on a Riemannian manifold. If the property that I mentioned doesn't hold, how could we transfer things to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ so that we can use known results in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Could you pls give me a hint? I am not so familiar with things on manifolds.